# Shell Script para localização de arquivos e diretorios

Tags: algoritmo-de-busca, bash, shell-script

Gostaria que alguem pudesse me ajudar a criar esse script de maneira correta, no caso é pra criar um script que voce digita o nome e o diretorio de um arquivo e depois indique se foi localizado ou nao e que gere esse tipo de saida na tela

1. $ ./localiza.sh
2. Digite o nome do arquivo: arquivo.txt
3. Digite o nome do diretório: /home/usuario/Documentos
4. O arquivo arquivo.txt não foi localizado no diretório
   /home/usuario/Documentos

Ou

1. $ ./localiza.sh
2. Digite o nome do arquivo: arquivo.txt
3. Digite o nome do diretório: /home/usuario/Codes
4. O arquivo arquivo.txt foi localizado no diretório /home/usuario/Codes

Eu fiz mas não ficou totalmente correto

```
#!/bin/bash

# localiza.sh

# script para localizar arquivos e diretórios

echo "Digite o nome do diretório: "

read DIR

echo "Digite o nome do arquivo: "

read ARQUIVO

#

find $DIR -name '$ARQUIVO' && echo "Busca efetuada com sucesso!" || echo "Arquivo não encontrado"
```

Comment: O que ocorreu? Algum erro?

Comment: Mesmo que não encontre o arquivo mas encontre o diretório a mensagem é sempre a mesma.

Comment: Sempre aparece a mensagem busca efetuada com sucesso mesmo que o arquivo não exista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz umas modificações no seu código e funcionou aqui:

```
#!/bin/bash

# localiza.sh

# script para localizar arquivos e diretórios

echo "Digite o nome do diretório: "

read DIR

echo "Digite o nome do arquivo: "

read ARQUIVO

X=$(find $DIR -name "$ARQUIVO")

#
[ -n "$X" ] && echo "Busca efetuada com sucesso!" || echo "Arquivo não encontrado!"
```

Comment: Valeu amigo, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Fumero se eu consegui responder sua dúvida, marque minha postagem como solução no lado esquerdo. Valeu!

Comment: Opa colega tinha esquecido de fazer isso,resolveu sim minha duvida, foi mal.